# What are these heat sink components?

Tags: heatsink

This is my first time dismantling a laptop. I was wondering what are those two components above the heat sink in the picture?

[image]

Comment: Looks like part of the heatsink

Comment: Do you mean the foam? Looks like some kind of insulating foam.

Comment: It would probably help if you were to give the model of the motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thermopads and foam.

Thermopads provide good heat transfer between their sides. They are used as heat conductors between components that may get hot and the heatsink. It's like thermal paste, except they have some thickness. (The thermal paste layer has virtually no thickness, it's there only to fill in the tiny space between the heat source and heatsink.)

Thermopads are worse conductors than the thermal paste, but they're good enough to cool less heat-intensive components, such as power delivery circuitry on a motherboard or graphics card. They are also easier to replace and less messy. Plus if you're designing a heatsink for a product you can use thermopad's thickness to pad component's height so that it reaches a heatsink that must be mounted higher to fit other components.

The foam is pretty common in laptops. I think its only purpose is filling gaps to guide the air into the radiator, rather than around it.